# Motivation for Kervaire's seminal paper

Tags: differential-topology, math-history

Let DIFF denote the category of smooth manifolds, TOP the category of topological manifolds and PL the category of piecewise linear manifolds.

In [Kervaire 1960](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kervarf.pdf) it is shown for the first time that there exists a topological manifold that does not admit a differentiable (and therefore certainly not a smooth) structure.

I am interested in knowing the motivation for Kervaire to find the invariant and the manifold discussed in the paper.

My thoughts on it: At the beginning of topology it was not known whether DIFF = TOP. One possible reason could therefore have been to show that they are not equal. Another reason I could think of might have been his intent to work towards a resolution of the differentiable generalized Poincaré conjecture. Maybe there are more possible motivations that I failed to think of. If anyone knows the true motivation I'd be very grateful to know it.